# convert multiline comma separated textbox values with single quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have a code which converts the multiple selected items from listbox into a single line with comma separated values. now i want to achieve the same thing in multiline texbox, in multiline textbox the values will be like abc,def,pqr now i want to separate it for searching in database 'abc','def','pqr'. the below code i am using is for listbox how to modify it so that i can use it for textbox purpose

```
 var SB = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (ListItem lst in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (lst.Selected)
        {
            SB.Append("'" + lst.Value + "',");
        }
    }
    var FinalString = SB.ToString().Substring(0, (SB.Length - 1));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: this code is working fine for listbox selection. i want to achieve same thing using multiline textbox

Answer (score 3):

```
String.Join(",", txt.Lines.Select(s => "'" + s + "'"))
```

String.Join is a method that gets a separator as first argument and a sequence of strings as the second. It solves the problem out of the box and more importantly solves the "last comma" problem which is so annoying when doing it with loops. You may use this method for the listbox code.

The second argument maps an array of strings to the same strings with added single quotes. Basically it takes a bunch of strings and applies the transformation to each of them and returns a bunch of transformed strings. The transformation is represented in the lambda expression.

Comment: @Stilgar : i want to achieve this by using textbox. in a simple way  my textbox getting values abc,def,pqr i want this to be made as 'abc','def','pqr' i want this to add it in a select statement

Comment: First of all I have given you the code to do so (assuming that you are using textbox with Multiline property set to true) and second you do not do this to get values into SQL because the system will be vulnerable to SQL Injection